# SymPy replace method with Wild does not correctly identify the exponent

Tags: python, sympy

I use SymPy for recognition and replacement of pattern, and it worked great. For example:

```
import sympy as sym
mu = sym.symbols('mu')

a=sym.Wild('a')
b=sym.Wild('b')
c=sym.Wild('c')
```

and now

```
I1=36*sym.exp(12)*mu**2
I1.replace(c*sym.exp(b)*mu**a,a,exact=True)
```

returns 2. But when I tried to recognize simple power function I had this:

```
I2=36*mu**2
I2.replace(c*mu**a,a,exact=True)
```

returns 36. Strange result, but moreover:

```
I2.replace(c*mu**a,c,exact=True)
I2.replace(c*mu**a,a*c,exact=True)
```

returns 36 too.
Then I found out next:

```
I2.replace(c*b**a,a,exact=True)
1
I2.replace(c*b**a,b,exact=True)
mu
I2.replace(c*b**a,c,exact=True)
1
```

so why sympy act like that, and if it is a bug can I make it works some way. Of course I am waiting  for this result:

```
I2.replace(c*b**a,a,exact=True)
2
```

Next example is

```
I2=12*mu**2 
I2.match(c*mu**2)
{c_: 12}
```

but

```
I2.replace(c*mu**2,c)
12*(1/mu)**(2/mu**2)/mu**2
```

I use python 3.6.5 and sympy 1.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Match

To recognize a pattern, use `match` method:

```
I2.match(c*b**a)  # {a_: 2, c_: 36}
I2.match(c*mu**a)   #  {a_: 2, b_: mu, c_: 36}
```

Specific values can be retrieved from the dict: `I2.match(c*b**a)[a]` returns 2.

#### Replace

The approach with `replace` is problematic in that SymPy may find sub-expressions and replace those, while ignoring the larger structure. For example,

```
I2.replace(c*mu**a, sym.sin(a) + sym.cos(c), exact=True)
```

returns `36*(cos(1) + sin(1))**2`. Here we see `mu` by itself matched the pattern with `a=1` and `c=1`, and was replaced so.

Same thing happens with your example: the subexpression `mu` got matched by `1*mu**1` and replaced with 1, leaving `36*1**2` which is 36.

This can be avoided by *excluding 1 from possible values of Wild*:

```
>>> a = sym.Wild('a', exclude=[1])
>>> c = sym.Wild('c', exclude=[1])
>>> I2.replace(c*mu**a, a, exact=True)
2
```

The `exact=True` flag ensures that "the match will only succeed if non-zero values are received for each Wild that appears in the match pattern", which still allows for the value to be 1. Specifically excluding 1 fixes that.

---

In the example with `I2=12*mu**2`, the replacement `I2.replace(c*mu**2, c)` finds several matches. For example, the exponent 2 matches the pattern because `2 = (2/mu**2) * mu**2` where the expression in parentheses is taken as c. To prevent this, indicate that c should not include mu:

```
>>> c=sym.Wild('c', exclude=[mu])
>>> I2.replace(c*mu**2, c)
12
```

Comment: Both ways worked, thank you, but I added next example, I cant recognize this type of problem there.

Comment: See the addition at the end of the answer.